# What are important items should I carry if I am plannig for 200 - 400 km

Tags: maintenance, touring, touring-bikes, preventative-maintenance

I am planning a tour for 200-400km by tar road. What precautions should I take during the tour.

- How much distance should I cover per day?
- How much speed should I maintain and what gear setting shall I prefer for less dehydration and other problems?
- What items should I carry for cycle maintenance?
- What items should I carry in first aid kit?
- What precautions should I take during tour?
- I have hybrid bike for this tour is it fine for this tour.
  http://www.bsahercules.com/Product-Features.asp?pid=200
- Other tips are also welcomed.

[image: Hercules Act 110]

Comment: when you go out for a "normal" ride today, what sort of distance do you cover? What's the maximum distance you've ridden in a day? how fast do you normally ride?

Comment: @PeteH I usually ride 20 km in 45-50 min in morning and 20 km in 45-50 min in evening. only once in week.

Comment: @PrasadSDeshpande You should train a lot more, or plan to go very slowly.

Comment: For your first aid kit question, see: [What are important items for a touring first-aid kit?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/318/what-are-important-items-for-a-touring-first-aid-kit?rq=1)

Comment: That's a bit difficult - you're not riding slowly but obviously you're doing pretty short distances, and infrequently. I mean, when I go touring its not unusual for me to cover 100-150km in a day, but I'm doing 4-5 hour rides quite regularly apart from this. If you're only riding 20km at a time, 100km is a big leap up. I think you definitely need to try some longer distance rides, as much as anything to make sure the bike is comfortable for that length of time.

Comment: Pretty sure this has been covered in pretty good depth some time in the past 2 years (since I joined).

Comment: See http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5321/equipment-for-a-multi-day-bike-trip and http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3868/what-are-the-most-important-things-to-bring-on-a-ride

Comment: This question seems pretty broad. Would you consider splitting into smaller, more specific questions and making sure that each hasn't been covered previously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How many days do you have for the tour?

Just about anyone (including my polio self) can do 60 miles (100 km) in a day, so long as there aren't too many hills and there isn't a bad headwind.  Rain will slow you down (and can make the ride miserable) but won't stop you unless it's very heavy or the weather is especially cold.  (Hail, on the other hand, *can* stop you.)

100 miles a day (160 km) is reasonable for someone who is fairly well trained, if the weather and hills cooperate.  And most people who aren't quite so well trained can do that distance "unreasonably" if pressed.

Hydration isn't necessarily a big deal.  You should have at least two 16 oz water bottles (readily accessible), which you fill several times a day.  You don't need more unless you'll be far from civilization or riding in unusually hot conditions.  Drink before you're thirsty.  Get in the habit of taking a swig every 10 minutes or so.

For maintenance you need mainly tire repair tools and a multi-purpose tool made for bikes.  For first aid a few Band-Aids, some antibiotic ointment, maybe some gauze and tape.  And your water bottle (for washing off wounds).  Your likely injuries are minor cuts from sharp edges of the bike plus "road rash".  Also have sun lotion and bug spray.  And some hydrocortisone ointment is nice to have for bug bites and "butt burn".

Precautions:  Wear a helmet!!!

Nothing wrong with that bike, for such a short trip.  Just keep the tires inflated to the max sidewall pressure.  If you were biking across the US you might want something different.

Comment: I am biking in India.

Comment: @PrasadSDeshpande - Like I said, the bike is probably fine for that distance.  In India I'd guess that water is usually available (though the quality may vary), the roads may tend to be on the rough side, and it's apt to be warm and humid.  35 mm tires (which you appear to have) are probably a good choice.  You likely will not be inclined to "race", so the handlebars are OK (the main negative being that they don't offer alternate hand positions -- consider getting bar extensions).

Answer (score 1):

1. In my experience it is normal to cover about 150-200 km in a day (provided you are well trained and equipped).
2. The speed you can maintain is dependent on many factors like your training, type of bike (hybrid/mtbs are slower than road/touring with drop bars) and also the nature of terrain, weather, etc.
3. Spare tubes, tire levers, pump, patch kit, tools like allen wrench/ spaner set suitable for your bike, brake/shifter cables, lights, batteries, etc.
4. Basic first aid kit with neosporin, bandage cloth, cotton swabs, bandaids, asprin, any other medication you need/use.
5. Be seen. Wear bright clothing, ride your bike defensively. Take breaks as necessary. Get cycling shorts/bib shorts. 
   I would change the saddle from that picture, it looks uncomfortable for long rides. Eat before you are hungry and drink before you get thirsty. Very easy to bonk on long rides if it is not supported and the rider is not consuming enough food/water.

Training is mandatory, I trained for about 12 weeks before I did my first 160 km ride. After the ride I felt I that should have trained more.

If you haven't bought the posted bike, I would suggest you to look into road style bike/ touring bike with drop handle bars.