# What to get? How do I know whether what I'm looking at is a BSO? (Bicycle Shaped Object); what should I do about the multiple chainrings?

Tags: chainring, bso

I'm about to get a ridiculously cheap bike (~$200) sometime soon and have limited my options to two bikes.

One is the BTwin Riverside 120, which people here in India who have put up reviews don't seem very happy about..

https://www.decathlon.in/p/8389398/bikes/hybrid-cycle-riverside-120-grey-yellow

Another one is Mach City Munich 21 speed.

https://machcity.com/munich-21-speed/

The reviews I've read about it are great everywhere I've read them on the internet, and the bike store guy also said that it's a great bike (he's trusted). However, since both are different brands, he couldn't draw out a comparison of which one would be better..

Anyone who can help? It'd be primarily ridden on bad Indian roads (image attached for reference, that's not how all parts of the road are, but significant enough to be considered).

Both have 700×35c stock tyres and can accommodate 38c tyres as well.

If I choose to buy a Mach City Munich 21 speed, I'd also like to know if I should simply remove two chainrings of three (if they're detachable, which I am yet to find out) to help "ease" my riding? It'd be mostly ridden on flat terrain with maybe a 50m 5-6% climb, so I'm not sure, but I don't really think I have any practical use of three chainrings.. By ease, I mean I want to eliminate the risk of putting the chains through a lot of stress and risking the chain falling off every now and then while also causing more wear and tear to the parts than is supposed to happen. I happen to be a student who doesn't really want to go to a bike repair shop all the time, so I'd try maintaining it myself, I've obtained resources for the same in a previous question of mine, thanks to the community here.. If the suggestions still remain to keep the triple chainrings, how to I "properly" shift gears? Is there any guide for the same?

Since I'm buying a rather "expensive" bike for the first time, what else should I be getting with the bike? I've currently understood that I should be getting a helmet, a good quality lock, mud-guards that cover the whole wheel (we actually have a monsoon season), a bottle stand, and a bell. I won't be buying lights because I am not thinking about riding in the dark. I want the bike to last as long as it can, so should I also get a chainstay protector? Anything else that I should be getting?

How do I know something is a BSO (Bicycle Shaped Object)? I also want to know whether any of them are a BSO? I don't even clearly understand what BSO means, given the fact that I don't have a "proper" bicycling experience (I've only ever ridden a ~$60-70 ss bike as of yet).. Are BSOs bad to have?

I've read various questions related to BSOs here but none seemed to answer my query.. I may have missed out on a relevant one though, but I tried not to.

Comment: I can't seem to add, or if added, see the image, so here it is. https://static-toiimg-com.cdn.ampproject.org/i/s/static.toiimg.com/photo/msid-65191037/65191037.jpg

Comment: In the US a "BSO" is a bike that sells for under $100 or so.  Generally a single speed or maybe 7-speed.  Usually single-piece cranks.  All steel (often including the rims) and heavy.

Comment: @Timon don’t be put off by the 3 chainrings, just because it has triple chainring, you don’t always need to use all of them.

Comment: @Dan K, I'm not really put off by it, I just don't want to cause unnecessary hassles related to maintenance (fewer parts means fewer maintenance, if I loose two chain rings, I also get rid of the front derailleur) and also don't want to be stopping every now and then because the chain came off..

Comment: @Daniel, both the bikes above are steel, and I don't know what your definition of heavy is, but at least the riverside 120 weighs about 15 kilograms along with the accessories.. Steel, from what I've understood, can take more of a beating than aluminum, and is also comparatively easy to repair.. Calling the bike "expensive" (for me), I'd like it to last for a while too..

Comment: $200 doesn't seem "ridiculously cheap" to me.

Comment: Agreed, @thosphor.  That's not a trivial amount of money.

I'm not sure what brands are common in India, so I don't know what to suggest, but here it the US my first thought would be to look in classified ads for non-BSO bikes.  A used bike may be much better, even if outdated, simply because of the standards it meets, both for parts compatibility and manufacturing tolerances.

Comment: Ride the bike for a while before you decide to remove chainrings!

Comment: Both bikes look kind of decent in the photos, the only major red flag is that advertisement claims triple chainrings but photos and detailed specs show a single one. A true BSO would already have full suspension at this price point.

Comment: @thospor, that's what I've been getting to hear everywhere, hence...

Comment: @ojs I guess the website developer did changes, because even at the time of writing the post, the image showed triple chainrings and there was a mention of a front derailleur as well so I won't really consider it a red flag, just a mistake that I'm hoping will resolve itself.

Comment: We have a Riverside 120 and we do like it. Decathlon quality can be a bit uneven at times, so I strongly recommend buying it at the shop (just in case you were considering buying online), so that you can examine it. What else to buy: Over here, this model came with the bell, and a transparent sticker on the chainstay (which is all the chainstay protection you need for this type of bike). In some countries it also comes with lights, but I would not consider these lights either safe (too dim) or reliable.

Comment: If you ask for a kick stand, they will likely offer one that mounts under the bottom bracket, as it fits on this bike. I do not recommend this kickstand because it interferes with the crank arms when the kickstand is in use. This is a nuisance when working on the bike. I'd suggest one that clamps on the chainstay (but wrap the chaninstay in some tape before mounting it, to prevent damage to the paint).

Answer (score 4):

That Munich "21-speed" is really a 7-speed. It doesn't have a triple chainring or front derailleur (and doesn't seem to have a planetary-gear rear hub). Not sure why they call it that.

Both bikes seem pretty comparable. Decathlon is well-known in Europe as selling cheap but decent products. I've never heard of Mach City. If a brand's reputation is worth anything, that's something to consider.

One of the hallmarks of terrible BSOs that I've seen in the USA is thin stamped dropouts with tubes that are pinched onto them (see below). Neither the Mach City nor the Decathlon bike seem have this kind of construction. Another hallmark is the [one-piece crank](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/opc.html).

[image: Pinched tube & rear dropout]

Comment: My preference is for riverside 120 as well but I don't think there's space for mud guards to be added on it, the ones that cover the whole wheel.. At least they sell nothing like it in decathlon stores or the Indian website.. I'm not sure if I can purchase a mud guard from elsewhere and be able to fit it without drilling holes in the frame..

Comment: I forgot to add that I've seen someone ride the bike on the road.. It did have triple chainrings.. It may be that they decided to ditch the triple chainrings in the newer version and the person who looks after the website didn't pay heed to making the changes properly.. Because even at the time I wrote the post, there were triple chainrings in the picture clearly and there was a mention of the same in the description of components as well.. Can you now tell me what to do about the triple chainrings? I mean, that if they're there.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the term "[BSO](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/887#887)" for bicycle-shaped object: in a city where some bicyclists can afford top-quality bikes, if you were to make a list of models of new bicycles for sale locally and sort by price, there would be a few models that are very expensive, several that cost much less, and typically not very models in between.  The term "BSO" is an insulting term for the models in the lowest group.

I rode BSOs for years and depended on them as my primary mode of transportation, and learned to love bicycles in the process.  I would recommend that you not waste much time trying to figure out if the label applies to a particular bicycle.  Just understand that the term as used here applies to lower-quality bikes.  Even cheap bikes can provide efficient and reliable service for years if they are used carefully and maintained well.

Here's my advice:

- Buy the best quality bike that you can afford.
- If you don't know much about bicycles, a knowledgeable friend can be very valuable when buying a bicycle, especially if the bicycle is used.
- Buy essential accessories at the same time you buy the bicycle, so factor the cost of the accessories when you calculate what you can afford.
- Don't skimp on safety, unless you have absolutely no other alternative.
- For non-essential accessories, consider riding the bike for a while first before buying the accessories so that you get a better understanding about what might be worth the money.
- Advice from people who understand your specific situation is worth more than advice from people who live in different climates and different situations.
- If you are at all mechanically-inclined, learn to maintain and repair your own bicycle.
- Having friends that you can learn from and share tools with is a good thing.

Comment: That's the problem, the only person around whom I know of who has even a bit of knowledge regarding bicycles is a shop owner who will obviously only know about the particular brands that he's selling... There's a cousin but he owns a Yeti bike and has absolutely no clue about what to buy at such a "pathetic" price point.

Comment: It sounds as though you may as well flip a coin to pick between bikes.

Answer (score 1):

Both look like perfectly decent bikes for low requirement riding, like commuting or  recreational riding.

I would take into consideration two things: fit and the reseller.
For fit, it sounds like you can try both.  Typically Decathlon will allow fitting the bike (even if only in the shop) and the local bike shop might even allow you to ride it outside.

As to the reseller: if the local bike shop selling the Mach has a good reputation, you might have a bit more recourse on the shop if a problem occurs.  I also think it's good to support a LBS by buying a bike and accessories from them.

Decathlon on the other hand sells tons of accessories that are typically compatible with the bikes they sell.  That means you can always buy parts later on.  That also makes it more suitable if you intend to do most of the maintenance on the bike yourself.

Good luck and enjoy the riding!

Answer (score -6):

> Both have 700×35c stock tyres and can accommodate 38c tyres as well.

Good! Although if your area has a real winter, it might be a bit limiting to fit studded tires in. Is this 35c / 38c tire clearance with or without mudguards?

> If I choose to buy a Mach City Munich 21 speed, I'd also like to know if I should simply remove two chainrings of three (if they're detachable, which I am yet to find out) to help "ease" my riding?

No, no, a thousand times no, unless you're planning to retain the front derailleur and the shifter.

I have removed the small ring on a 26T/36T/48T crankset because it's just so ridiculously small for my uses. But it wouldn't be a crime to retain it.

If you have only one chainring, the chain is prone to drop off the chainring, requiring you to get your hands dirty in chain oil whenever that happens. It's a major annoyance.

There are three conditions that allow chain drop to be a non-issue:

1. If you have a front derailleur and the front shifter, the chain is unlikely to drop, and when it drops, you can operate the front derailleur to re-raise the chain on the chainring.
2. If you have a chainguide, the chain is very unlikely to drop. This may depend on the design of the chainguide: some are better than others and there is no standard for chainguides.
3. If you have a narrow/wide chainring (needs to have an even tooth count for it to be possible) **AND** a clutch-type rear derailleur (e.g. Shimano Shadow Plus) **AND** you have enabled the clutch by turning the switch on the rear derailleur, the chain is very unlikely to drop. Note that the clutch needs to be disabled to easily remove the wheel and re-enabled after installing the wheel. A clutch-type rear derailleur and a narrow/wide chainring will not help at all if the clutch is disabled, as I have found.

> I've currently understood that I should be getting a helmet

It's debatable. Bicycle helmets are very weak, much weaker than motorcycle helmets. Due to the ventilation needs, they may not be strong enough to prevent brain injury. However, if you choose to select a helmet, run through this checklist:

1. The helmet should be an in-mold type, i.e. it should have a polycarbonate structural part that is molded in to the expanded polystyrene. Cheap helmets don't have the polycarbonate structural part molded in.
2. The helmet should have [MIPS protection](https://mipsprotection.com/) to prevent rotational brain injury. If it doesn't, you may be putting yourself in more danger when wearing a helmet than when not: a helmet increases the likelihood the head rotates violently when crashing, thus making it possible to get rotational injury.
3. The helmet should be [Snell certified](https://smf.org/) as only Snell certified helmets are dropped from 2.2 meter height. United States CPSC certified helmets are only dropped from 2.0 meter height and European EN-1078 certified helmets for (oh the horror!) 1.5 meter height. Note here that the actual height of your head does not matter, because the constant angular momentum puts more linear momentum in your head than in your toes. Thus, because of this constant angular momentum, your head is effectively dropped from 1.5 times of its actual height, when falling. So if your head is at 1.8 meter height, ideally the helmet would be tested by dropping from 2.7 meter height.

> a good quality lock

Select the smallest quality U-lock you can find. Smaller locks are harder to get a hydraulic jack in, and harder to find space to run an angle grinder without damaging the bicycle itself. Smaller locks are lighterweight, too. For me, my choice is the Kryptonite Evolution Mini 5 lock.

> mud-guards that cover the whole wheel (we actually have a monsoon season)

I recommend Hebie Wingee. They combine mudguards and 8+8kg capacity pannier rack to the same lightweight part, and are very sturdy. It's much lighterweight to mount the panniers directly to the rear mudguard. Note that when driving in the rain, the water spray from your front tire will still make your toes wet even if having a mudguard.

> a bottle stand

Not necessary. I used to ride 50 km rides, and never once needed water. If the theoretically unlikely occurrence of needing water happens, you are usually less than 10 km away from a grocery store. So replace the bottle stand with a credit card, unless you are riding in very remote locations.

> a bell

Yes! Don't forget lights and reflectors. German law requires (I follow the German law even though I'm not in Germany):

- at least two red rear reflectors
- at least one white front reflector -- I use two
- tubular spoke reflectors in every spoke OR at least two yellow side reflectors per wheel OR a reflective strip around the tire -- I prefer the tubular spoke reflectors in every spoke
- yellow pedal reflectors facing front and rear on both pedals
- a non-blinking red light to the rear
- a non-blinking white light to the front with a beam pattern that produces useful visibility and vision without blinding oncoming traffic

> I won't be buying lights because I am not thinking about riding in the dark.

Note most jurisdictions make reflectors mandatory even if not riding in the dark, and there are jurisdictions that make lights mandatory even if not riding in the dark. Also, you may find yourself needing those nevertheless.

> I want the bike to last as long as it can, so should I also get a chainstay protector?

Unnecessary. It is not a reasonable failure mode preventible with a chainstay protector for a chainstay to fail.

> Anything else that I should be getting?

You need [the most important things to bring on a ride](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3868/what-are-the-most-important-things-to-bring-on-a-ride). Plus a floor pump you keep at home, because it's a pain to inflate tires with a mini pump.

If you need to park the bicycle standing often, consider a kickstand.

If you transport stuff with the bike, consider quality panniers (Ortlieb is one good manufacturer).

A cyclocomputer would be useful but not a necessity.

Bicycling shoes, preferably of the types that attach to the pedals AND that you can walk in out of the bike. So this pretty much limits you to SPD shoes. They require SPD pedals; I prefer Shimano PD-T8000 as the PD-T8000 has reflectors and at the same time allows you to ride the bike in regular shoes.

Bicycling clothes for all kinds of weather you're planning to ride in and gloves are heavily recommended. The clothes should be synthetic, because cotton holds a lot of water (i.e. sweat), making you cold when sweaty.

The saddle should fit to your anatomy. For most, it means around 14 .. 15 cm wide saddle that is fairly hard. A soft saddle or a too wide saddle means you're sitting on the muscles that propel you forward, which is not a good situation in the long run. Any saddle hurts a lot if not being accustomed to bicycling. Ride 300-500 km and the saddle pain goes away.

If you maintain the bike yourself, tools plus an inventory of the most common spare parts.

> How do I know something is a BSO (Bicycle Shaped Object)?

Look at the hubs. They should be Shimano. Other hubs are likely to fail early, and hub is the second most difficult component to change in the bike.

Look at the rims. They should be aluminum, and have eyelets around the spoke holes. Ideally, they would have double eyelets. However, I wouldn't call something a BSO just because the rims lack eyelets around the spoke holes, if it's otherwise a good bicycle.

Ideally the front and rear wheel would both have 36 stainless steel spokes, triple-butted (2.34mm at head, 1.8mm middle, 2.0mm at threaded end) and the nipples would have a spherical seat (e.g. DT Swiss Pro Head), but if I labeled this as a recommendation of a bicycle as opposed to a BSO, I would be heavily downvoted. (I still may be, as I dared to question the usefulness of less than 36 spokes per wheel.)

Look at the frame specs. If it says "hi-ten steel" it's a BSO. Quality frames are butted chromium-molybdenum steel or hydroformed aluminum. The frame is the most difficult component to change in the bike.

Look at the fork. If it's a cheap suspension fork, it's a BSO as opposed to a bicycle. Suspension forks have their place in more expensive mountain bikes, but unless you're planning to spend a lot of money on the fork (and thus the bicycle), a rigid chromium molybdenum steel fork is a much better choice.

Look at the seatpost. If it has a cheap clamp with finite adjustment positions, or a clamp separate from the seatpost, it's a BSO. (However, if this is the only problem making the object a BSO as opposed to a bicycle, it's easy to remedy -- replace the cheap seatpost and clamp with a good quality two-bolt infinitely adjustable seatpost.)

Comment: I think I’d rather have a water bottle just incase the next grocery store is more than 10km away.

Comment: I am sure a chainstay protector would not be bad, if the chain is chipping the paint off the chainstay the steel will rust pretty soon

Comment: It is a complete nonsense to say that only one brand makes good hubs. Even bigger nonsense than requiring 36 spokes. The same for pedals. Firstly, flat pedals are certainly a valid option, secondly, there are multiple MTB clipless pedal/cleat brands (CB, Speedplay).

Comment: I also wonder how you are going to mount "yellow pedal reflectors facing front and rear on both pedals" on SPD pedals.

Comment: "Smaller locks are harder to get a hydraulic jack in, and harder to find space to run an angle grinder without damaging the bicycle itself. " U locks are actually opened by a nail gun https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJxcpht4zKw no one is going to bother sawing it.

Comment: OP" '...here in India...', this post: 'if your area has a real winter'. Hmm.

Comment: Even though bicycle helmets are very weak compared to motorcycle helmets, they still save many lives and reduce the severity of many injuries every year.

Comment: Most new bicycles come with a decal that serves as a chainstay protector.  That's always been enough for me.  @Timon you could always try a piece of duct tape (strong thick plastic tape) as an additional protector; if the chain scratches through it, you know you need a better protector.

Comment: I disagree about helmets saving many lives. The widespread misconception about the dangers of riding bicycle and the need to have a helmet is pushing many people away from riding bicycles, to a stationary lifestyle. Yes, bicycle related head injuries reduce in number and severity -- enforce a mandatory helmet law and the percentage of head injuries reduces approximately by the amount bicycle riding reduces. However, diseases related to the stationary lifestyle (diabetes, cardiovascular disease) more than outweigh what was saved by the helmet law discouraging bicycling.

Comment: @juhist DT Swiss, i9, Hope, Chris King.... they all make good hubs, some arguably better than Shimano. At $200, I wouldn’t be bothering with worrying about hub branding; focus on comfort and bike fit instead. About helmets: is it really that hard to wear one? It’s just a piece of riding gear (helmet, shoes, gloves, and glasses) that you don every ride. I imagine the hard and slippery outer shell of a helmet is better at preventing rotational injuries than your hair and scalp.

Comment: Let's not restart a helmet debate in comments, please.

Comment: @VladimirF [Some SPD](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/deorelx-t670/PD-T421.html) pedals have these reflectors built-in, precisely to comply with (German) road laws, so you can get a street-legal bike with clipless pedals. As these are typically for commuter bikes, they also have a flat side for ordinary shoes.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/other-states/leh-coldest-recorded-place-in-ladakh-mercury-marks-improvement-in-kashmir/article30073514.ece

Comment: @VladimirF Altitude isn't the same as winter but point taken